# Datastax c# Cassandra throwing exception after update to 3.X

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

I've just upgraded the driver from 2.7.3 to 3.0.3 and seems like something weird was done with the Mapper.Single() . It was just working on the old version but now throws an exception;

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Cassandra.dll ("Argument types do not match")
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    timezone frozen<timezone>,
    language frozen<language>,
    bank set<frozen<bank>>,
    name text,
    country frozen<country>
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS timezone (
    id uuid,
    name text,
    time int
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS language (
    id uuid,
    name text,
    iso text
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS bank (
    id uuid,
    name text,
    number int
);
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS country (
    id uuid,
    name text,
    iso2 text,
    iso3 text
);
```

Mappings

```
For<Client>()
            .TableName("client")
                  .PartitionKey(u => u.Id)
                  .Column(u => u.Id, cm => cm.WithName("id"))
                  .Column(u => u.Name, cm => cm.WithName("name").WithSecondaryIndex())
                  .Column(u => u.Timezone, cm => cm.WithName("timezone"))
                  .Column(u => u.Language, cm => cm.WithName("language"))
                  .Column(u => u.Country, cm => cm.WithName("country"))
                  .Column(u => u.Banks, cm => cm.WithName("bank"));


UdtMap.For<Timezone>()
                 .Map(u => u.Id, "id")
                 .Map(u => u.Name, "name")
                 .Map(u => u.Time, "time")
UdtMap.For<Bank>()
                .Map(u => u.Id, "id")
                .Map(u => u.Number, "number")
                .Map(u => u.Name, "name")
UdtMap.For<Language>()
                  .Map(u => u.Id, "id")
                  .Map(u => u.Name, "name")
                  .Map(u => u.Iso, "iso")
UdtMap.For<Country>()
               .Map(u => u.Id, "id")
               .Map(u => u.Name, "name")
               .Map(u => u.Iso2, "iso2")
               .Map(u => u.Iso3, "iso3")
```

C# Code

```
public static class CassandraConnection
    {
        private static Cluster Cluster;
        public static String Keyspace { get; set; }
        public static String[] Addresses { get; set; }
        public static String Username { get; set; }
        public static String Password { get; set; }
        public static ISession Session { get; set; }
        public static MappingConfiguration MappingConfiguration { get; set; }
        public static IMapper Mapper { get; set; }
        public static void Conectar()
        {
            Addresses = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Cassandra.Addresses").Split(';');
            Keyspace = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Cassandra.Keyspace");

            Username = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Cassandra.Username");
            Password = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Cassandra.Password");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Username))
            {
                CassandraConnection.Cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints(Addresses).Build();
            }
            else
            {
                CassandraConnection.Cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints(Addresses).WithCredentials(Username, Password).Build();
            }
            CassandraConnection.Session = CassandraConnection.Cluster.Connect(Keyspace);
            MappingConfiguration.Global.Define<MapCassandra>();
            Session.UserDefinedTypes.Define(UdtCassandra.Udts());
            CassandraConnection.Mapper = new Mapper(CassandraConnection.Session);
        }

    }



 public class CassandraRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseDomain
    {
        public T GetById(T entity)
        {
            if(CassandraConnection.Session == null)
            {
                CassandraConnection.Conectar();
            }
            if (entity != null)
            {
                return CassandraConnection.Mapper.Fetch<T>("WHERE id = ?", entity.Id).FirstOrDefault(); //That should be just SingleOrDefault() but im testing stuff;
            }
            return default(T);
        }
}
```

StackTrace

```
 em System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Condition(Expression test, Expression ifTrue, Expression ifFalse)
   em Cassandra.Mapping.MapperFactory.GetExpressionToGetColumnValueFromRow(ParameterExpression row, CqlColumn dbColumn, Type pocoDestType)
   em Cassandra.Mapping.MapperFactory.CreateMapperForPoco[T](RowSet rows, PocoData pocoData)
   em Cassandra.Mapping.MapperFactory.CreateMapper[T](RowSet rows)
   em Cassandra.Mapping.MapperFactory.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<GetMapper>b__0(Tuple`2 _)
   em System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   em Cassandra.Mapping.MapperFactory.GetMapper[T](String cql, RowSet rows)
   em Cassandra.Mapping.Mapper.<>c__DisplayClass7`1.<FetchAsync>b__6(Statement s, RowSet rs)
   em Cassandra.Mapping.Mapper.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ExecuteAsyncAndAdapt>b__1(Task`1 t2)
   em Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.DoNext[TIn,TOut](Task`1 task, Func`2 next)
   em Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete(Task task, Int32 timeout)
   em Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete[T](Task`1 task, Int32 timeout)
   em Cassandra.Mapping.Mapper.Fetch[T](Cql cql)
   em Cassandra.Mapping.Mapper.Fetch[T](String cql, Object[] args)
   em CassandraWebTest.Repository.Cassandra.CassandraRepository`1.GetById(T entity) na C:\Users\devb0194\Source\Workspaces\CassandraWebTestV3\CassandraWebTest.Repository\Cassandra\CassandraRepository.cs:linha 124
   em CassandraWebTest.Business.Security.Client.GetById(Client Client) na C:\Users\devb0194\Source\Workspaces\CassandraWebTestV3\CassandraWebTest.Business\Security\Client.cs:linha 63
   em CassandraWebTest.Business.Security.UsuarioAutenticacao.Authenticate(UsuarioAutenticacao usuarioAutenticacao) na C:\Users\devb0194\Source\Workspaces\CassandraWebTestV3\CassandraWebTest.Business\Security\UsuarioAutenticacao.cs:linha 95
   em CassandraWebTest.Web.Controllers.LoginController.Authenticate(String usuario, String senha, Boolean persistente) na C:\Users\devb0194\Source\Workspaces\CassandraWebTestV3\Web\CassandraWebTest.Web\Controllers\LoginController.cs:linha 38
```

This code works fast and perfectly on 2.7.X but doesnt work on 3.X.X drivers.

Comment: Are you using hardcoded parameters in the query or  parameter placeholder?

Comment: It looks like a driver issue, can you post the stack trace?
Anyway, remember to use query markers instead of hardcoded parameters as adviced in the documentation: http://docs.datastax.com/en//developer/csharp-driver/3.0/csharp-driver/reference/mapperComponent.html

Comment: Added code for better explanation.

Comment: Could you post the schema of the table and the class that is failing. Have you check if you are using the expected type in the query (ie: Guid if the id is of uuid cql type)?. Another pointer: [reuse the cluster instance across your application](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra).

Comment: Information added. Thanks a lot, its always good to have DataStax people around! Seems like I'm following the recommendations about the parameters and how connections should be used, I think this is most likely a driver issue or just lacking some configuration by my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error was due one of the POCO's got a reference to a frozen type using IList instead IEnumerable.

That used to work on 2.7.X but doesnt work on 3.X.X.

Thanks a lot Jorge!